# how to do optional nullable template wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11

How to represent a type which is optional and also nullable, i.e. can be explicitly set to null?

Is there something in the standard library or boost?

Otherwise I thought to do something like:

```
using boost::optional;

template<typename T>
class optnull : public optional<optional<T>>
{
public:
    bool isSet() { ...; }
    bool isNull() { ...; }
    T& get() { ...; }
};
```

is that good?

Comment: Where is from the ``optional``?

Comment: `std::optional` is optional and nullable.  There is `std::nullopt` to set an `optional` to "null"

Comment: `boost::optional`

Comment: Does `optional<optional<T>>` mean you want two distinct non-`T` values (omitted, and null)?

Comment: In my solution's sketch, the outer `optional` template class is meant to indicate wether the field is set; the inner `optional` is meant to indicate wether the contained value is null or not.

Comment: Why using inheritance ?

Comment: `std::variant<std::nullptr_t, std::nullopt_t, T>`?

Comment: The more I think about this, the less sense it makes. This could only be useful for a `T` that's not inherently nullable, but I struggle to imagine a scenario where that wouldn't be very confusing.

Comment: T is not nullable. And you're right about the fact it is confusing. It's confusing also for me. I'm taking the specification of [a jsonrpc protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#initialize) (which happens to be in TypeScript) and try to implement those message classes, but when I encounter a message field such as `processId?: number | null;` I read "a field that can be missing, can be null, or can be a number" (which makes me scratch my head), so perhaps the server is going to distinguish a missing field from a field which is explicitly set to null?

Comment: @fferri In that case, nullability is clearly a property of T, not of the optional, so you probably want `boost::optional<boost::variant<std::nullptr_t, double>>` to represent that. (replace boost with std in c++17)